# 'Cannot find name' in Typescript class constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am getting a 'Cannot find name' error when I inject a service into a class by inserting the imported name into the arguments of the constructor. This has happen a few times to me now and I can't figure out what fixes it. Any light shed on this would be much appreciated. Here is my example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { _ } from 'lodash';
import { RatesService } from '../../services/RatesService';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Currencies } from '../../models/currencies.ts';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-rates',
    templateUrl: 'rates.html'
})

export class Rates {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        private ratesService: RatesService,
        private currencies: Currencies) { }
}
```

'Currencies' causes the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typescript compiler is giving us a misleading error string.

Change:

```
 import { Currencies } from '../../models/currencies.ts';
```

to

```
 import { Currencies } from '../../models/currencies';
```

Comment: explanation? I thought extension is optional not prohibited